# Can I test EM r/a/t of some materials using a spectrum analyser and how do I do so?

Tags: product-engineering, radiation

I am a hobbyist and I was wondering if I can test electromagnetic (radiowave range) reflectance/absorbance/transmittance of some materials using a spectrum analyzer and how do I do so?

Comment: @jsotola electromagnetic reflectance/aabsorbance/transmittance .

Comment: isn't that how the chemical composition of interstellar gas is determined?

Comment: @jsotola no i see that the word spectrum did confused you. I am talking about [this](https://youtu.be/iIBB_XvqnGM?si=ZgEiufUaIvWV3jfR)

Comment: @Tintin so is what you link to a Spectrum Analyser? If not then we may not be the ones confused...

Comment: @SolarMike what do you mean?

Comment: this question good for the EE stack

Comment: @PeteW EE doesnt treat materials sheet and steups of a system to test shielding RF neither ham radio do that i think i am in the right place i guess but if the members say otherwise i will delet my post sure.

Comment: @PeteW a spectrum analyzer helps to compare the power of the signal source and the power reflected or transmitted if so thats my idea or at least my understand then the setup that i have in my head is to make a box of lead with two place of antennas in an angle that i have figure out and a place for the sheets that i want to test what do you think?

Comment: @PeteW the purpos of the materials sheet is to shield against electromagnetic radiation in the radiowave range so am not interest in the "phase"  or signals; so and as i know and understand in an EM wave, the magnitude of the electric field is proportional to the magnitude of the magnetic field. For th EE i will give it a shoot .

Comment: @PeteW [here you go](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/698682/can-i-test-the-em-shielding-of-a-material-with-a-spectrum-analyzer)